# TYPO3 decode realurl in userfunc

Tags: typo3, realurl

I have made an userFunc to make nice urls in my own extension.

How do I decode the urls so that TYPO3 will show the right product?

I think that the uid of the product will be somewhere so that I can use it.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you don't have to decode anything. RealURL sets the `$_GET` variables back to what they would be if RealURL wasn't used. So if your URL contains...

```
&tx_origkentaurproducts_kentaurproductsfe[action]=show
```

...and RealURL transforms it for example to...

```
/action/show
```

...then when such URL is being displayed, you should still have your data available in...

```
$_GET['tx_origkentaurproducts_kentaurproductsfe']['action']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how things look at our projects:

```
function main($params, $ref) {
    if ($params['decodeAlias']) {
        return $this->alias2id($params['value']);
    } else {
        return $this->id2alias($params['value']);
    }
}
```

So do whatever your alias2id needs to do.
Maybe add the uid in the URL as a part.
So you have something like *productname-productcolor-productsize-**2938202*** as your segment.
Explode the segment by '-' and pop it off your array and return it. Might save you a SQL query as well.