# Decode RealUrl url in the controller

Tags: typo3, extbase, realurl

I use RealUrl for my website. In my certain extension, I require to decode the url created by RealUrl to the normal TYPO3 url format.

Example:

To my controller I get this link : `typo3website/feature/number/123` , now how do I convert this to `typo3website/index.php?id=99&number=123`

The RealUrl does not use namespace, and hence i'm unable to understand how to create an instance of the class tx_realurl.

I tried using `require_once(PATH_typo3conf.'ext/realurl'.'/class.tx_realurl.php');` and creating new instance of tx_realurl, but gives a class not found error.

Comment: lorenz's answer should be good but you can also see my explanation in another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909340/typo3-decode-realurl-in-userfunc/19927146#19927146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If RealURL is configured properly and the link is generated with the uriBuilder or the ActionViewHelper, you don't need to take care of that. If we take your example and you configured RealURL to use `typo3website/feature/number/123` for `index.php?id=99&tx_yourext[number]=123`, you can use this as argument for your action:

```
public function showAction($number) {
}
```

You can also access all arguments from a controller action by using

```
$this->request->getArguments()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is not generated using UriBuilder, but is mapped and configured using RealUrl

Comment: How is it generated then? Using typolink?

Comment: This solved the issue, I added `tx_myExt_myExt[number]` to my argument and it works fine now.